# Ag-grid: How disable cell click event when enableCellTextSelection is used and text is selected?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Using ag-Grid Community and Angular, I set [`[enableCellTextSelection]="true"`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/#clipboard) to enable cell text selection to facilitate copy-paste, but I found that the `cellClicked` event still fires when text is selected and the mouse button is released (*i.e.* the mouse is clicked, dragged and released in the same cell).

Is there a way to detect that text is selected in the `cellClicked` event and "cancel / quick exit" it?

I looked for a way to distinguish between the mouse down and mouse up coordinates but couldn't find anything...

Thanks.

---

*Version in use*

- ag-grid-angular: 23.2.1
- ag-grid-community: 23.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little workaround you can use. Use `window.getSelection()` to get the text selected by the user. From this, you can determine if text has been selected or not.

Change your `cellClicked` callback function to this:

```
cellClicked(event)
    {
      if (window.getSelection().type !== 'Range')
      {
        //text has not been selected, the cell has been clicked
        console.log('cellClicked');
      }
    }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-nyfnds?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks! I would have loved for it to be an "ag-grid official way", but your way seems to do the trick if none other exists :)